# Best android virtual device setup (AVD setup)

Tags: android, testing, open-source, android-virtual-device

I was wondering if there is some main stream AVD (Android Virtual Device) suite?

The problem is that i just want some fast testing for small applications that shows some images, text, etc. and does no heavy calculations.

I want this to be tested visually fast and for "normal" phones so I dont have to have a full beast of a phone.

**What are ok specs for the AVDs to test with?**

Preferably:

1. Fast
2. Open Source
3. Linux Compatible

Comment: if you want fast testing your app I suggest you to use your device directly, don't forget to activate your debug mode in your phone. IMHO, AVD is slow and need more RAM usage, you can set small dimension, use the old android version and set the emulator RAM wisely or use genymotion as your emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Genymotion emulator (http://www.genymotion.com) seems to be aimed at providing fluid and streamlined emulator experience, and has been gaining notoriety recently.

Comment: I would like to have Open Source options also.

Comment: I think you're going to be hard-pressed to find emulators in general, let alone active open source projects. Good luck!

Comment: Setup Genymotion Android Emulator in Linux (http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/07/learn-to-setup-fastest-genymotion.html)

Answer (score 1):

AVDs available with adt bundle you can launch a virtual device from Android virtual device manager(AVD works fine with +2GB RAM).
If you have a android phone you can use it for development it gives you fast result.

Comment: The normal AVDs available in the adt bundle are slow even though you got a fast CPU like a intel i7.

Comment: I have suggested a physical device too for fast development.

Comment: Ok, if the option is a physical devise wich one works well from your experiences like drivers and compatibility etc. Is the Nexus series a good choice?

Comment: Instal HAXM (new Acclereted Emulator from Intel) through the SDK manager and use Intel Atom (x86) instead of the ARM (armeabi) for the CPU of the device you create.
This should be pretty fast ;)

Comment: i am using micromax A110 and it's working fine although you can use any device just install the necessary drivers and enable usb debugging from developer options from settings.

Comment: HAXM Speeds Up the Slow Android Emulator (http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html)